# R session aborts when using vcf2geno code

Tags: r, rstudio, vcf-vcard, genome

I'm beyond frustrated trying to get this code to run again. This code worked before and I submitted the assignment in full, but I am trying to use it for my project and now running this code causes R to abort the session.

The code is as follow:

```
library(LEA)
setwd("/Users/Changirwa/Desktop/COURSES/BIOL 468")

vcf2geno(input.file = "data/pika_subset.vcf", output.file = "data/pika_subset.geno")

geno2lfmm(input.file = "data/pika_subset.geno", output.file = "data/pika_subset.lfmm")
```

I attempted to knit the file to see what it would say and this is what it said:

*** caught segfault ***

address 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'

```
Traceback:

1: vcf2geno(input.file = "data/pika_subset.vcf", output.file = "data/pika_subset.geno")

2: eval(expr, envir, enclos)

3: eval(expr, envir, enclos)

4: withVisible(eval(expr, envir, enclos))

5: withCallingHandlers(withVisible(eval(expr, envir, enclos)), warning = wHandler,     error = eHandler, message = mHandler)

6: handle(ev <- withCallingHandlers(withVisible(eval(expr, envir,     enclos)), warning = wHandler, error = eHandler, message = mHandler))

7: timing_fn(handle(ev <- withCallingHandlers(withVisible(eval(expr,     envir, enclos)), warning = wHandler, error = eHandler, message = mHandler)))

8: evaluate_call(expr, parsed$src[[i]], envir = envir, enclos = enclos,     debug = debug, last = i == length(out), use_try = stop_on_error !=         2L, keep_warning = keep_warning, keep_message = keep_message,     output_handler = output_handler, include_timing = include_timing)

9: evaluate::evaluate(...)

10: evaluate(code, envir = env, new_device = FALSE, keep_warning = !isFALSE(options$warning),     keep_message = !isFALSE(options$message), stop_on_error = if (options$error &&        options$include) 0L else 2L, output_handler = knit_handlers(options$render,         options))

11: in_dir(input_dir(), evaluate(code, envir = env, new_device = FALSE,     keep_warning = !isFALSE(options$warning), keep_message = !isFALSE(options$message),     stop_on_error = if (options$error && options$include) 0L else 2L,     output_handler = knit_handlers(options$render, options)))

12: block_exec(params)

13: call_block(x)

14: process_group.block(group)

15: process_group(group)

16: withCallingHandlers(if (tangle) process_tangle(group) else process_group(group),     error = function(e) {        setwd(wd)       cat(res, sep = "\n", file = output %n% "")        message("Quitting from lines ", paste(current_lines(i),             collapse = "-"), " (", knit_concord$get("infile"),             ") ")    })

17: process_file(text, output)

18: knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)

19: rmarkdown::render("/Users/changirwa/Downloads/rlab3.Rmd", encoding = "UTF-8")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on so I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I just bumped into the same error with a student, we had this code:

```
library(LEA)
input_file <- 'outliers.vcf'
vcf2geno(input_file, 'output')
```

which crashed with the same crash. **The solution: outliers.vcf does not exist in that location, fixing the path to the correct path fixes the crash.**

Background: I checked and it runs some C code internally (`.C('R_vcf2geno', input, output, 0, 0)`) which throws up with the same error of memory not mapped, making R crash.

It turns out that the R_vcf2geno C code doesn't handle non-existing files at all, it crashes and takes R with it.

The student was using setwd() to get into the working directory of outliers.vcf, but when we reran the code the setwd() wasn't run, and `outliers.vcf` didn't exist in the current working directory. Check whether your input file actually exists in the location you give to LEA!

Edit: **Later we also found a malformated vcf file that caused the same crash** (the vcf file had extra quotation marks from having been saved in Excel once). Running the vcf2geno command in the R-console in the terminal instead of RStudio helps, because then the C-code vcf2geno runs will actually print a helpful error message before crashing R. You don't see that error message in RStudio.